# Почему вылетает SEGFAULT при использовании слота?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qml

В Qml файле у меня есть кнопка на которой 2 текстовых поля для в ввода,по нажатию на кнопку,данные из этих полей считываются и обрабатываются,но почемуто после нажатия кнопки после гдб проверки вылетает сегфолт и указывает на QObject* 
 а точнее сказать на find cildren ,в чем может быть причина?

```
 void Logger::coClicked(const QString& in){

 QObject* textinput4 =  this->parent()->findChild<QObject*>("textinput4");
 QObject* textinput5 =  this->parent()->findChild<QObject*>("textinput5");

    QString str1=(textinput4->property("text")).toString();
    QString str2=(textinput5->property("text")).toString();

    float min = str1.toFloat();//Переведем строку в число
    float max = str2.toFloat();//Переведем строку в число
    if((max >_coMax.toFloat())||(min<_coMin.toFloat())){
        emit alert();
    }
    emit coChanged();
}
```

Comment: я QT не знаю, но  название метода подсказывает, что   он не может инстанцироваться  базовым классом

Comment: вы вызываете сигнал coChanged() и судя по названию coClicked тоже сигнал. Он инстанцируется после обработки MOC. Возможно этот метод должен быть слотом и соединяться с сигналом QPushButton::pressed?

Comment: Rikitikitavi , соClicked это слот.

Comment: segfault происходит при первом вызове findChild? viewer тогда это что? указатель точно валидный?

Comment: @bronstein87 я переписал эти строки чтоб было понятнее, указатель идет на родителя класса

Comment: что возвращает qDebug() << this->parent() ?

Comment: @bronstein87 QObject(0x0) , нулевочку, как ее не назови,почему так выходит не знаю.

Comment: так а родитель у вашего логгера есть? покажите конструктор Logger и создание экземпляра класса

Comment: причина сегфолт - обращение по нулевому указателю, который возвращается this->parent()

Comment: @goldstar_labs   Logger(QObject *parent = nullptr)

    Logger logger;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("logger", &logger);
    engine.load(url);

Comment: вы создаете логгер и не указываете его родителя, поэтому вам метод this->parent() возвращает нулл и всё падает. Укажеите родителя или в конструкторе или через setParent()

Comment: @goldstar_labs а если обратиться просто   this->findChild<QObject*>("textinput4");